# Get difference between first and last instance in hour

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr

How do I get the difference between the last price recorded in the hour and the first price? Using dplyr would be nice.

Please see below for my dput dataset:

```
structure(list(DATETIME = structure(1:20, .Label = c("2007-05-30 09:41:00", 
"2007-05-30 09:45:00", "2007-05-30 10:22:00", "2007-05-30 10:37:00", 
"2007-05-30 10:39:00", "2007-05-30 11:25:00", "2007-05-30 13:21:00", 
"2007-05-30 14:01:00", "2007-05-31 09:38:00", "2007-05-31 09:56:00", 
"2007-05-31 11:02:00", "2007-05-31 11:09:00", "2007-05-31 11:56:00", 
"2007-05-31 11:57:00", "2007-05-31 13:42:00", "2007-05-31 14:12:00", 
"2007-05-31 14:25:00", "2007-05-31 15:39:00", "2007-05-31 15:48:00", 
"2007-05-31 15:55:00"), class = "factor"), MINUTE = c(41L, 45L, 
22L, 37L, 39L, 25L, 21L, 1L, 38L, 56L, 2L, 9L, 56L, 57L, 42L, 
12L, 25L, 39L, 48L, 55L), HOUR = c(9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 
13L, 14L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 
15L), DAY = c(30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L), MONTH = c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L), YEAR = c(2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L), AV.PRICE.BIL = c(45.79, 45.75, 
45.79, 45.79, 45.79, 45.79, 45.8, 45.8, 45.79, 45.8, 45.8, 45.8, 
45.8, 45.8, 45.8, 45.8, 45.8, 45.8, 45.8, 45.8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), .Names = c("DATETIME", "MINUTE", "HOUR", "DAY", "MONTH", 
"YEAR", "AV.PRICE.BIL"))
```

Sample output wanted:

```
DATETIME             MINUTE     HOUR     DAY     MONTH     YEAR     AV.PRICE.BIL   HOURLY.DIFF 
2007-05-30 09:41:00  41         9        30      5         2007     45.79           0          
2007-05-30 10:22:00  22         10       30      5         2007     45.79           0
2007-05-30 11:25:00  25         11       30      5         2007     45.79           0
2007-05-30 13:21:00  21         13       30      5         2007     45.79           0
```

So if there are any missing hours, it simply subtracts the observation from last recorded hour from the current hour.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `xts`?

Comment: What should the `MINUTE` and `AV.PRICE.BIL` refer to? From which row (first or last) should they come?

Comment: MINUTE is the minute component of datetime. AV. PRICE. BIL is the average price of a stock. Difference should be last observation in first hour - last observation in previous hour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `first` and `last` functions make this rather trivial.

I `mutate` and `slice`, instead of `summarise` since you seem to want to keep the first instances of `DATETIME`, `MINUTE` etc.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR) %>% 
  arrange(MINUTE) %>% 
  mutate(HOURLY.DIFF = last(AV.PRICE.BIL) - first(AV.PRICE.BIL)) %>% 
  slice(1)
```

> ```
> Source: local data frame [10 x 8]
> Groups: YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR [10]
>
>               DATETIME MINUTE  HOUR   DAY MONTH  YEAR AV.PRICE.BIL HOURLY.DIFF
>                 <fctr>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>        <dbl>       <dbl>
> 1  2007-05-30 09:41:00     41     9    30     5  2007        45.79       -0.04
> 2  2007-05-30 10:22:00     22    10    30     5  2007        45.79        0.00
> 3  2007-05-30 11:25:00     25    11    30     5  2007        45.79        0.00
> 4  2007-05-30 13:21:00     21    13    30     5  2007        45.80        0.00
> 5  2007-05-30 14:01:00      1    14    30     5  2007        45.80        0.00
> 6  2007-05-31 09:38:00     38     9    31     5  2007        45.79        0.01
> 7  2007-05-31 11:02:00      2    11    31     5  2007        45.80        0.00
> 8  2007-05-31 13:42:00     42    13    31     5  2007        45.80        0.00
> 9  2007-05-31 14:12:00     12    14    31     5  2007        45.80        0.00
> 10 2007-05-31 15:39:00     39    15    31     5  2007        45.80        0.00
> ```

Comment: I just noticed there are some hourly differences that weren't picked up. i.e. rows 4 and 3 (in the original data there was a missing hour) but the difference should be between the price at hour 11 and the price at hour 13, which is 0.01, but it wasn't picked up.

Comment: How to keep the last instance of the DATETIME in each hour instead of the first?

Comment: actually i found a way. arrange(desc(MINUTE)) worked